Markdown в базе данных SQL для телеграм бота
Телеграм бот aiogram берет текстовое значение из таблицы с номером карты. Он должен отправить его пользователю в жирном/моноширинном формате. Но как бы я не изменял значение в базе данных ничего не помогает. Бот все равно отправляет обычный текст без какого-либо форматирования. Как сделать, чтобы бот выводил текст из базы данных в моноширинном формате?
Я пробовал заносить в базу данных текст изначально в формате, окружая его ** или ``, но ничего не помогает. HTML разметка тоже.

Markdown может быть сохранён в базе данных как обычный текст, но он обрабатывается и применяется только при отправке сообщения через бота. Рекомендую посмотреть документацию по форматированию текста в Aiogram https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/utils/formatting.html //измените пожалуйста ваш вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
